# How can I save text with formatting in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm working on a Chrome Extension that has a notes page as a feature. It's not the main feature (meaning it won't be a lot of text) so I don't need to store the notes in a database, so I plan on storing the notes in LocalStorage.

Is there a way I can store this text with formatting such as new lines. For example, I want  the following text:

Hello,

world.

to be saved as is, instead of "Hello,world."

Comment: Line breaks are saved in local storage, check the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lxkophfn/).

Answer (score 1):

To format the text, you need to use:

```js
    const formattedText = text.split('\n').join("\\n")
```

To get the text back, you should use:

```js
    const text = formattedText.split('\\n').join('\n')
```